# Shell tool to move in a complex directory structure

Tags: linux, shell

My development machine is a linux host.

I have a complicated directory structure (like most of you, I assume), and I would like to move easily from one directory to the other, from within the shell. Specifically, welcomed features would be:

- autocompletion (something like ido-mode in emacs)
- regular expression directory / file matching
- suggestion of recently visited directories (stack).
- Possibilty to push/pop to the stack, get a listing of recently visited directories, ...
- good integration of those features
- console based

Do you know any tool which can satisfy those requirements?

Comment: Should be in unix or superuser, not a programming question.

Comment: @Tom Zync: do you know how to move the question over to another forum?

Comment: I flagged it for those who can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, any interactive shell(say, bash) already has nearly all of these features:

- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once to auto-complete, and twice to show a list of possible completions.
- `find | grep reg.exp` can be used for file matching, or `find -exec grep reg.exp -H '{}' ';'` to match contents
- You can switch to the previous directory with `cd -`
- `pushd` and `popd` can be used to push and pop directories

Comment: Sure, all those tools are working fine, and I use them regularly. But I use them so often that I need something less "keyboard intensive". That is why I stressed "good integration". In the ideal scenario, a couple of keystrokes would offer me a list of options which most closely match what I am looking for - similar to what ido-mode in emacs does.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can set CDPATH to a colon-separated directories that bash will search for when the argument to the cd does not exist.

```
$ man  bash|grep -A3 '^\s\+CDPATH '
CDPATH The search path for the cd command.  This is a  colon-
       separated list of directories in which the shell looks
       for destination directories specified by the  cd  com‐
       mand.  A sample value is ".:~:/usr".
```

Once set, autocomplete will just work the way you'd expect it:

```
$ export CDPATH=dir1:dir2
$ cd somedir<tab>
```

Besides the current directory, bash will look into the directories in $CDPATH for the possible values.